# c# draw a pie chart to a tab

Tags: c#, charts, tabs, pie-chart, graphic

Pretty simple Question, unfortunatly never used draw controls etc in C# so im not sure how to look at this.
Ok, im drawing a piechart from a bunch of textboxs for input and running the draw on a button event.
i need to draw the chart on one of my tabs instead of the from background.  how do i set it?
heres my code:

```
      private void tempButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle tabArea;
        RectangleF tabTextArea;

        Bitmap B = new Bitmap(500, 500);

        tabArea = tabControl1.GetTabRect(0);

        tabTextArea = (RectangleF)tabControl1.GetTabRect(0);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(B))
        {
            int i1 = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            int i2 = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            int i3 = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
            int i4 = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);

            float total = i1 + i2 + i3 + i4;
            float deg1 = (i1 / total) * 360;
            float deg2 = (i2 / total) * 360;
            float deg3 = (i3 / total) * 360;
            float deg4 = (i4 / total) * 360;

            Font font = new Font("Arial", 10.0f);
            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
            p.Width = 0.5f;

            tabArea = new Rectangle(textBox1.Location.X + textBox1.Size.Width + 250, 150, 500, 500);

            Brush b1 = new SolidBrush(Color.Gold);
            Brush b2 = new SolidBrush(Color.Silver);
            Brush b3 = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkOrange);
            Brush b4 = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

            g.DrawRectangle(p, tabArea);

            g.DrawPie(p, tabTextArea, 0, deg1);
            g.FillPie(b1, tabArea, 0, deg1);
            g.DrawPie(p, tabTextArea, deg1, deg2);
            g.FillPie(b2, tabArea, deg1, deg2);
            g.DrawPie(p, tabTextArea, deg2 + deg1, deg3);
            g.FillPie(b3, tabArea, deg2 + deg1, deg3);
            g.DrawPie(p, tabTextArea, deg3 + deg2 + deg1, deg4);
            g.FillPie(b4, tabArea, deg3 + deg2 + deg1, deg4);

            //set picturebox3 as data source??
            pictureBox3.Image = B;

        }
    }
```

As you can see when i click the test button it draws the chart but behind my tab area, i need it to draw onto one of my tabs(i got a feeling this is super easy 1line solution, but google is not my friend atm ).
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't really know, but I'd TRY putting a picture box on tab control... getting the graphics from that picture box, and drawing on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to create a bitmap of the desired dimensions, create `Graphics` for this bitmap, do the drawing and then set this bitmap as the image source for an auto-sizing picture box you place on the tab. This is the cleanest way.

**UPDATE**
I noted in my comments that your drawing code is not well thought through. Change the first lines as follows:

```
    Rectangle tabArea;
    RectangleF tabTextArea;

    Bitmap B = new Bitmap(500, 500, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    tabArea = new Rectangle(0, 0, B.Width, B.Height);
    tabTextArea = new RectangleF(0, 0, B.Width, B.Height);
```

Also: Determining `tabArea` based on control locations is not a good idea.
Lastly: Set the "SizeMode" property to "AutoSize" to have the picture box stretch to the bitmap dimension.

Comment: many thanks for the response, i've had a go at creating a bitmap and adding graphics and drawing to that.  not sure how to set the bitmap as the source for the picturebox? ill update my code ::UPDATED::

Comment: ah i think pictureBox3.BackgroundImage = B; should work ill post my solution soon (i hope)

Comment: No, `pictureBox3.Image = B;` is the correct code. Otherwise, autosizing will not work.

Comment: there seems to be a problem. Ive got the graphics to display on the tab(many thanks!0, but for some reason there is no color and the image is squashed horizontaly even though the picture box is same Hieght and Width.  is there something wrong with pictureboxes and manualy setting graphics? (yeh changed to image) but same problem of no color etc

Comment: Look at the code you posted: You're not using the bitmap's dimensions, but `GetTabRect(0)`. Change that to `B.Size`. Also, there are some overloads for `Bitmap`'s constructor - there is one that takes with, height and the `PixelFormat`. Use a pixelformat for colors and alpha-value (Format32bppArgb).

Comment: ah i see now what you mean idd i can change the size(hurray).
OK so last would be the brushs. as you can see im creating new brushs inside my graphics using.  then passing those into my .fill.  how would i translate this into pixel format?

Comment: oh wow, i took out my tab area location and it seem it will now pass colors.....strange, why was this the reason? due to me setting its location but by constructing it, its values were set to defualt for color?? or am i way off?

Comment: I don't really know. If you have a bitmap that supports color, you're doing it right already. As soon as you tell the bitmap to be color, you should also see color. Maybe you were drawing outside the bitmap's bounds?

Comment: true, ill look into that problem. thanks alot for your help! (btw im looking at the image and my god it looks rubbish! xD but atleast i know the basics into using it now)